# Wordpress error in formatting.php

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting

Since I moved the website to another server I'm getting this error on the frontend where that categories are:

```
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /public/sites/www.siteurl.nl/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1529

Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /public/sites/www.siteurl.nl/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1981
```

Code on line 1529:

```
if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
```

Code on line 1981:

```
$title = strip_tags($title);
```

What is this error and how can this be solved?

Update:

This is the frontend:

[image]

It's showing categories from the jobs that are on the site. Which I can select on the backend side:

[image]

Regards,
Robert

Comment: See if this helps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/php-warning-preg-match-expects-php-warning-strip-tags

Comment: You need to show us how are $title and $string initialized. The warning means what it says, the code considers the variables objects instead of strings, so I would like to see what is put there.

Comment: Show the value of `$string` and `$title`...

Comment: What's inside $string and $strip_tags?

Comment: First of all, this is not the error that triggers from WordPress Core. These two methods are used inside sanitize_title_with_dashes() and remove_accents() methods. Which means in theme/plugin you are passing an object instead of a string.

Comment: I've moved the website back to the old server and the error is gone...